# Why space complexity of adjacency list representation is O(V+E) not O(E)?

Tags: c++, data-structures, graph, graph-theory, adjacency-list

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
const int N=1e3;
vector <int> graph2[N];
int main(){
    int n,m;
    cin>> n>>m;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        int v1,v2;
        cin>>v1>>v2;
        graph2[v1].push_back(v2);
        graph2[v2].push_back(v1);
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<graph2[i].size();j++){
            cout<<graph2[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

I am creating a adjacency list representation of a tree and using above code and found on the internet that its space complexity is O(V+E) not O(E) why?
I am only using the vector for storing edges
like--

```
Input-  
6 9
1 3
1 5
3 5
3 4
3 6
3 2
2 6
4 6
5 6

Output - 
3 5 
3 6 
1 5 4 6 2 
3 6 
1 3 6 
3 2 4 5
```

I am using only storing the one part as v1---v2 then only storing v2 and v1 is the index by default so why we are assuming v1 in our space complexity?

Comment: size of adjacency list is the size of vertex. That's why you have O(V) part. For all edges, you need O(2E) if your graph is undirected graph. Note that you pre-allocated `1e3` for the vector which is not suggested. Why do you need that size? It may be set by user.

Comment: You have an array of vectors, I think you missed that part.

Comment: Consider empty graphs with `V` vertices (`E` = 0). As you increase V, you have to hold more empty adjacency lists, so the lower bound is o(V) (and O(E) with these graphs is O(1))

Answer (score 1):

You're using a fixed `N` and ignoring `n`, which makes it look like the space complexity doesn't depend on the number of vertices (you are essentially saying "every graph has 1000 vertices").

If you use a local `vector<vector<int>> graph(n);`, you see how the required space depends on `n`.

Answer (score 0):

An adjacency list representation of a graph should be an array where every cell represents the name of a vertex of the graph, so you have an array of |V| size, then every element of the array is linked to a list that contains all the edges starting from the vertex represented by the cell of the array.

So, in total, you have an array of |V| size and |E| nodes representing all the edges starting from each vertex ( O(|V|+|E|) ).

I hope I was clear.